# Similar function to R "rep" in jags to create array?

Tags: r, jags

Is there a similar function in `jags` as the `R` function `rep`? I want to create an array using similar code as the following:

```
n ~ dmulti(pi, N) # pi is a 3 dimensional probability vector, N is fixed
  # the dimension of n is hard coded in this line:
a <- c(rep(0, n[1]), rep(1, n[2]), rep(2, n[3]))
```

I read through the manual and wasn't able to find a way to achieve this. I understand that Stan would probably allow this but I couldn't use Stan because I need to do inference on discrete parameters. I really appreciate your help!

This question is also posted on the [JAGS help forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/74a66be0/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added a `rep` function to the development version (future JAGS 4.0.0) as Matt and John have alluded to, this requires the second argument to be fixed so that the length of the resulting vector can be determined at compile time.

Comment: There was a typo in my example code. n should be a sample from a multinomial distribution with size N, which is a fixed data.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, I'm afraid not. One of the stipulations of the JAGS/BUGS language is that variables must have fixed dimensions (with every element defined exactly once) - in your example a will change dimension size depending on the vector n. There may be other ways to get the result you are looking for, but not using this approach.

Incidentally, you use n twice in that bit of code (LHS and RHS of the multinominal distribution) which is not allowed - although that may just be a typo :)

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You could populate your vector with some loops:

```
library(R2jags)

M <- function() {
  for (i in 1:n[1]) {
    a[i] <- 0
  }
  for (i in 1:n[2]) {
    a[i + n[1]] <- 1
  }
  for (i in 1:n[3]) {
    a[i + sum(n[1:2])] <- 2
  }
}

j <- jags(list(n=3:5), NULL, 'a', M, DIC=FALSE)
j$BUGSoutput$mean$a

## [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

However, as @MattDenwood alluded to, if the sum of the elements of `n` is variable this will throw an error - `a` must be of constant length throughout the simulation.